# Typescript generics. Easy case of a type system break

Tags: typescript

Why does the following code is accepted by TypeScript:

```
export let repeat = <a> (a: a, n: number): Array<a> => {
  return [...Array(n).fill(a), 1] // <-- no error here (but should)
  // return [...[a], 1] // <-- an error here (as should)
}

console.log(repeat("x", 4))
```

tsconfig.json

```
"strict": true,
...
```

The `, 1]` is added to check the case. It's not meant to be a part of `repeat` logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are introducing an `any[]` when you use `Array(n)`. `Array(n)` will return an `any[]` so the result of the array spread will also be an `any[]` regardless of whatever else you put into the array. By definition `any` is assignable to anything including a generic type parameter, so the assignment succeeds.

Using the generic constructor you will get the error you expect:

```
export let repeat = <a> (a: a, n: number): Array<a> => {
  return [...new Array<a>(n).fill(a), 1] // <-- error now
}
```

You might also consider enabling the tslint rule [`no-unsafe-any`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unsafe-any/)  which would have probably caught this.